# Does location of # in query parameter URL affect on anything?

Tags: vue.js, url, hash, vue-router, query-string

Using Vue.js with routing mode hash.
When I access to this site, # will be autocompleted at the end of query parameter
( It will be like https://myapp.com/?foo=bar#/ )
and it works fine( getting the parameter and every other function.)

However, I saw several questions on Git saying,
" # will located at the wrong place ( at the end of query parameter ), how can I fix to myapp.com/#/?foo=bar "

My questions are

1. Is Hash locating at the end of query parameter a bad thing ? ( Does
   that affect anything? )
2. What is the difference of
   myapp.com/#/?foo=bar
   and
   myapp.com/?foo=bar#/

Thank you ahead.

Comment: `myapp.com/?foo=bar#/` means the fragment has a value of `/`. `myapp.com/#/?foo=bar` means the fragment has a value of `/?foo=bar`. These are fairly different URLs, and we don’t know which one you *want*.

Comment: @deceze♦
 
Thank you deceze for replying.

Is below what you meant ??

【myapp.com/?foo=bar#/ 　⇒　foo = bar is already a part of the parent fragment 】
                                                                                               
【myapp.com/#/?foo=bar    ⇒　the same parent fragment has a value of foo = bar】

Comment: Everything *after* `#` is the fragment and relevant to the Vue hash router. Anything *before* it isn't.

Comment: Thank you again, @deceze ♦
I understood. Does # being at the end of the query parameter has some bad effect like disturbing the browser history / vue.js does not recognize parameter sometime?

I heard from someone else but she said she was not sure as well so. If you know, I will appreciate it.